# Каким FTP клиентом пользуетесь Вы?

Tags: ftp

Cтолкнулся с проблемой загрузки файлов в Sublime Text 3 (SFTP). Хостер не понимает, в чём дело, а загрузка файлов через FTP-клиенты, такие как FileZilla, происходит успешно, а в Sublime Text 3 всё время выводит ошибку

> Multiple Disconnections error.

Решил, что нужно менять FTP клиент.

Какой из тех, которые Вы использовали можете мне посоветовать для загрузки файлов на сервер? Нужен удобный и красивый клиент :)

Comment: [*Какие вопросы лучше не задавать? не задавайте субъективные вопросы, в которых: любой ответ правильный, например, «Какой ваш любимый язык программирования?»;*](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: я не просто задал вопрос! мне нужно найти нормальный FTP! т.к. тут сидят хорошие программисты, я не думаю, что они редактируют файлы в блокноте, а потом загружают через FileZilla

Comment: Человек, задающий вышеописанный вопрос, писал бы *"я не просто задал вопрос! мне нужно найти нормальный язык программирования! т. к. тут сидят хорошие программисты"*, но это нисколько не сделало бы вопрос подходящим для StackOverflow. А [Справку](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help) всё-таки почитайте.

Comment: @ikerya `не думаю, что они редактируют файлы в блокноте, а потом загружают через FileZilla` - вы будете смеяться наверное, но лично я использую именно  FileZillaPortable - быстро легко и удобно, без проблем....а быстрое редактирование провожу именно в `notepad++ `....... чем это не нормальный инструмент для использования, мне вот неясно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну так вы может и не хороший программист ;)

Comment: @VladimirGamalian кек)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

например FileZilla (зачем менять???).

А вообще переходите на Sftp! Работаю в сублайме с ftp и с sftp - таких проблем не встречал. возможно вы неверно настроили этот плагин. настройки в студию!

Comment: через FZ  не удобно. настройки - http://pastebin.com/UcWqhbfa

Comment: а если так? (по умолчанию): http://pastebin.com/d6Rj2Gky